# Having trouble writing a function in R to modify list of data frames

Tags: r

I have a list ("years") of data frames, where each data frame is named by year:

```
type_of(years)
[1] "list"
names(years)
[1] "2008"  "2009"  "2010"  "2011"  "2012"  "2013"  "2013a"  "2014"  "2015"  "2015a"  "2016"
```

I have been trying to write a function which takes a list as an argument, takes all the data frames where the name ends in "a" (for "addendum") and then finds the matching year for the data frame (so "2013a" matches "2013"). The function will then perform a semi_join of the addendum on the matching year data frame, and returns a list containing only the unchanged and combined data frames.

```
#desired result
names(years)
[1] "2008"  "2009"  "2010"  "2011"  "2012"  "2013"  "2014"  "2015"  "2016"
```

I've tried several iterations, to no avail. Below is the latest function I've attempted and the error message it generates.

```
MergeAddA <- function(lst) {

#finds data frames with addendum  
adds <-grep("\\d{4}a+", objects(lst), value = FALSE)   

  #finds match for addendum and joins data frames
  for (add in adds) {
  
    add <- lst[[add]]
    
    add_to <- grep(gsub("a", "", add), objects(lst), value = FALSE, fixed = TRUE)
    
    add_to <- lst[[add_to]]
    
    semi_join(add_to, add, by = c("case_number", "job_order_number"))
  }
return(lst)
}

years  %>% MergeAddA()
Error during wrapup: attempt to select less than one element in get1index
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could help you.
However it would be better if you could share some sample data so we could check results.

```r
MergeAddA <- function(lst) {
  new_list <- list()
  
  for (name_loop in names(lst)) {
    
    # Names like "2012a"
    if (stringr::str_ends(name_loop, "a")) {
      name_clean <- substr(name_loop, 1, nchar(name_loop) - 1)
      new_list[[name_clean]] <- semi_join(
        lst[[name_clean]], 
        lst[[name_loop]],
        by = c("case_number", "job_order_number")
      )
    # Names like "2012" that aren't already in the new list.
    } else if (!name_loop %in% names(new_list)) {
      new_list[[name_loop]] <- lst[[name_loop]]
    }
  }
  return(new_list)
}
```